# Blocking access site with server ip in IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, hosting

Suppose that I have a server ip of 184.198.74.73 and domain of testing.com hosting in IIS 10? How can i block user from accessing the site with ip address?

**Problem description:**

Taking google.com as example. I ping google ip can get its ip address.
However I can't access it using IP address even using Postman.
How can this be done?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is just set the binding in iis for a site with the domain name. as shown in the below image.

[image]

you could set rule to do not allow host header to IP address:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="192.168.2.50" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
            </rule>
```

then you could set the iis IP and domain name restrictions if you do not want to allow specific IP address or range of IP address to access your site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions

Comment: How does this work with https over the same ip?